# Split Parse Server and LiveQuery Server setting can't get Event

Tags: parse-platform

According document http://parseplatform.org/docs/parse-server/guide/#scalability, I want to split Parse server with Express and Parse LiveQuery server. And two server setting like below. However, after start two servers, can't get ParseObject Event. Could anyone help?

My Parse Server index.js setup like below:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://192.168.200.45:27017/dev',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'AppID',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MasterKey', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  //javascriptKey: process.env.JAVASCRIPT_KEY || '',
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://192.168.200.45:1111/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['ProductCount'],
    redisURL: 'redis://192.168.200.45:2222'
  },
});
var app = express();


var port = process.env.PORT || 1111;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('App on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer,  {
  redisURL: 'redis://192.168.200.45:2222'
});
```

My LiveQuery Server setup like below:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');


var api = new ParseServer({
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'AppID',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'MasterKey', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://192.168.200.45:1111/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  websocketTimeout: 10 * 1000,
  cacheTimeout: 60 * 600 * 1000,
  logLevel: 'VERBOSE',
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['ProductCount'],
    redisURL: 'redis://192.168.200.45:2222'
  }
});


var app = express();


var port = 2222;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('LiveQuery Server running on port ' + port + '.');
});

// This will enable the Live Query real-time server
ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer,  {
  redisURL: 'redis://192.168.200.45:2222'
});
```

Comment: Hi! I'm in the same place as you are! I have a Parse Server where I run my app and store my db and I have another one for LiveQuery... That's where I'm stuck... I've seen Parse's documentation, but it's not much explanatory! Can you please tell me why do I need redis and how can I use it?

Comment: Hi, nice to hear someone also stuck this problem, then can discuss together. About Redis structure, you may check the below link, have explanation http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#scalability

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! If I got it right, I need to deploy somewhere the redis-server, correct?
If so, is it a good idea to install it on the server where my Parse Server is deployed, or should I do it on a separate one?

Comment: Also, does redis act like a load balancer? (like nginx) Or do I need to set up one, for the LiveQuery servers? (sorry for bombing you with questions, but I can't find answers anywhere :))

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?